# Concept demo for "Internet of Things & Social Network"

Tags: facebook, virtual, account

This is my first post in this facebook's stackoverflow forum. My background is on wireless baseband prototyping on FPGA platform and do not have any prior experience with facebook development. Now i have a chance to work on social network related development work and i'm quite excited. Anyway above is just my background introduction.

Here i want to create a virtual Facebook user. Imagine you are interacting with your refrigerator on Facebook. This is the kind of concept we want to show.

Following are the functionality i would like to have at my **virtual**'s facebook account..

1) recognize real friend check-in and messages posted on his/her wall.

2) ability to write messages on real friend's wall.

3) recognize messages posted on virtual account's wall.

4) ability to write message on virtual account wall.

How can the virtual account be equipped with such functionalities? Can i achieve by writing a facebook application? Please advise the direction i should look at.

Cheers,
Phone Naing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The facebook api lets you query their graph but it requires an access token to do that.
There are 3 main token types: User, Page and App.

Your app would be able to get an app token easily but it's limited to public data only, like data of public pages.
For a page and user tokens you'll need the actual user to interact with your app in order to get the token.

You can get the friends check-ins, feed, images, events and so on by asking for the right [permissions](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/) from the user (there are user permissions and friends permissions).
You can also post to friends wall with the "publish_stream" permission.

For "recognizing" posted items on a user wall you can either recheck the user feed every once and a while and compare what you had and what you get or use the [Real-time Updates](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/).

With all of that said, I seriously doubt that you'll manage to pull something like that with the current limitations of the facebook api.

Let's start with the fact that facebook does not like profiles to be "vritual", they want the profiles to be of real people.
Of course that there are plenty of virtual profiles but they can remove them (and sometimes do).

Even if you do have these virtual profiles, since they are virtual they won't interact with your application using facebook, that is won't be logged in to facebook via their channels (web interface, android or iOS, etc).
Because of that you won't be able to get a user access token which you need for all of the information you want.
Since the [deprecation of the offline_access permission](http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/) there's no way to have a token which is valid for a user for more than about 2 months, which means that for each "virtual user" you'll need to log him in to facebook and then interact with your app to get a new token.

You can create a page instead of a virtual profile, which will also be fine with facebook.
But here again, you need a user to actually interact with facebook and your app to get a valid page access token, and even if you get that, it's not enough for the data you want to ask for.

To put it all together:
I think it can't be done.

Comment: Hi Nitzan,

Thanks for your information. Since we are doing a concept demonstration, the refrigerator itself would be a laptop PC. And demo will only last for 2/3 hours. Before the demo, we can log in for virtual profile and interact with the application. During the demo, we expect the app helps virtual profile interact with a friend. In this kind of scenario, do you think the app is able to fulfill the requirements?

Cheers,
Phone Naing

Comment: You can use server side authentication and get an access token that will be valid for about 2 months, so under the demonstration you should be alright. What's the point in having a demo for something that doesn't work though?

Comment: Thanks again Nitzan. I want to emphasize that we are showing a *concept* demo so we can accept partial working solution at this moment. Here social network is not restricted to just facebook and Who knows in the future social network will tap into internet of things as well.. Cheers.

Comment: I'm wondering, which app hosting option is more sensible for my case, 1. Facebook hosted or 2. Hosting on own website ?

I have question regarding Graph API as well. Graph API only required for above hosting option 2 ?

Comment: There's no "facebook hosted" option. You can use Heroku which facebook partnered with, but that's not the same as hosting on facebook. You have to host things yourself.